# iOS - Top and bottom margin on control in horizontal UIStackView

Tags: ios, margin, uistackview

I am designing a prototype cell in Xcode to display events in my iOS app. At the moment I have the following design:

[image: Example of prototype design]

The cell is constructed like this:

- Stack View

  - Label (99:99)
  - View (Orange bar)
  - Label (Event title)

I would like to have a top and bottom margin on the orange bar of 2 pixels (basically not have the orange bar occupy the full height of the cell). I tried to add a top and bottom constraint on the View which looks like it is working, however Xcode is complaining about this solution (see screenshot).

[image: Xcode complaints regarding top and bottom constraints]

Can anybody help me on how I could best accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of you have just set top and bottom constrain. you also need to add other constrain. Just click on red round. and set add missing constraint.

**set constrain as shown in below.**

[Image of the constrain](https://i.imgur.com/4fu9AVZ.gifv)

**Edit:-**

[image]

View Hierarchy:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and demonstration. The problem is that the View (orange bar) is in a horizontal stack view. In my (very limited) understanding the stack view should take care of the correct constraints. Doesn't this conflict with setting the leading and trailing constraints?

Comment: Nope . you will not facing any problem regarding constrain. and you face any problem then just give trialing space to second label and leading space to first label. First try with this.

Comment: I am working on it, doing it like you mentioned doesn't work unfortunately. When I add the constraints as you mention it will stretch the View (even though I have a width constraint set to 2px).

Comment: can you upload your xib if possible ? width is same for orangeview in all the device ?

Comment: Thank you for all the help. The width of the orange bar is the same for all devices indeed. The current version of the .xib file can be downloaded here: https://route2it-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mvanbeusekom_route2it_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=tHz8tWeNEH6RFs%2fqQrFiZdHpBNfTz0eF2KZ6eS8oIow%3d&docid=0eaefc070b0dd4774b4e1ce9fc89b1807

Comment: why you have use stackview ? stackview is working only ios 9.0 and letter. if you will use it in before 9.0 than your app will be crash.

Comment: I know, I wanted to use stack view to learn about it. Second the app will run in a enterprise environment where I am sure all devices will run iOS 9 or higher

Comment: Download .xib from here . http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01832437105699167039 . you have alsmost set constrain properly but you havn't set update frame . check this.

Comment: Thanks, i am on road now I will check it immediately when I get back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103833/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-maurits-van-beusekom).

Comment: is it not helpful for you ?

Comment: No not really, I have posted a reply in the chat as you suggested but didn't get any feedback from you

Comment: i didn't find any message from your side.

Comment: even chat page not found.

Comment: I gave you xib also . have you check it ?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem remains however.. There is no top and bottom margin of the orange bar. It occupies the full height within the stack view.

Comment: Stackview is generally used for equal spacing , fill or etc. so, you can't set such type of set directly. so, you need to customview within stackview and then set size of orangeview according to your requirement. please check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, the trick with the custom view did the trick. Although in this case the UIStackView is a bit of an overkill it is a very good learning experience.

Comment: Thank you . Welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set View (Orange bar) height less than 4 pixels.After that set top space and bottom space of orange bar view to superview 2 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Amit. Your answer sounds logical, however since I am pretty new to Xcode, could you explain a bit more detailed where I can set the height to be less than 4 pixels? Do I do this with a height constraint?